# Entity Framework - Relationship in Table per Type Inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, relationships, table-per-type

I have the following situation in my model:

```
public abstract class Person 
{
public int PersonId { get; set; }
public int FullName { get; set; }

public int LanguageId { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
public int PersonId { get; set; }
.
.//some data
.
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
public int PersonId { get; set; }
.
.//some data
.
}

public class Language 
{
public int LanguageId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I used TPT approach for inheritance, and all run good. My problem: I want to add the Language Class, where a Person has a Language, and a Language has many Persons, so it's a one-to-many relationship. But in TPT approach Navigation Properties can't be inherited so I can not create the Language Object in Person class and neither the relationship in mapping class, I don't want to create a Navigation Property in Language Class because this table has a lot of relationships in my model, and I don't want to delete LanguageId in Person class 'cause it's a common property for all subclasses.

I've researched in several books, articles and here, but I've found nothing. In all examples explain the same situation (like [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)) but with the relationship in opposite direction.

I will appreciate your help, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you say in TPT approach Navigation Properties can't be inherited.

One solution would be to add a relationship to the Language class at the Teacher and Student Level.

Another would be to move to a table per heirarchy approach.